# Finding a reflection that exchanges two unit vectors

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $v$ and $u$ be two vectors in an Euclidean space, that have same length:$\|v\| = \|u\|$, but are not on a same line. Find a reflection w that commute/switch between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: What have you tried? Start by saying what's the definition of "reflection"

Comment: Did you think about it geometrically? Or do you know what the result should be but have trouble with coming up with algebraic formula for it?

Comment: @Aleks i know i can look at the plane created by v and u then look at their sum which is the vector u+v..and take a vector a that is orthogonal to the sum: u+v.knowing that S_a is the reflection that is defined by a. Then i do not see how it can be related !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This visual aid should give you a better idea of how to achieve what you're trying to achieve. The vector perpendicular to the reflection plane is seen to be

$ \frac{u - v}{|u -v|} $
let's call this vector $\hat{r}$

Then we can write down the reflection of any vector $x$ as:

$x \rightarrow x - 2((x - \frac{u + v}{2}) \cdot\hat{r} ) \hat{r} $ , so substituting we have:
$x \rightarrow x - 2((x - \frac{u + v}{2}) \cdot   \frac{u - v}{|u -v|} ) \frac{u - v}{u-v}$

now if we substitute for $u$ for $x$ then we have

$u \rightarrow u - 2 (\frac{u-v}{2} \cdot \frac{u - v}{|u-v|} ) \frac{u-v}{|u-v|}  = u - (u - v) = v$

And similarly it follow for v -> u. Or alternatively you can notice that it is antisymmetric in u and v.

Comment: then can i substitute x = u in this function and assume that it equals to v ?

Comment: You should check it yourself if it equals that, oh and a disclaimer : $\hat{r} = \frac{r}{|r|} $

Comment: I'm trying to use the function above but don't understand how the inner product work to show that it exchanges u and v!

Comment: I have edited my answer -- haveing thought about it I have found an easier way with just inner products. If you need more elaborations please ask.

Comment: it isn't a problem taking a reflection not of the usual form of x---> x-2(x v) v ?

Comment: Why don't you try and compute it? :)

Comment: Didn't understand which one you mean, i did compute the one you suggested, it works..but with the definition I can't find a suitable reflection